# print a form/panel in asp.net 2013

Tags: c#, asp.net, printing, webforms

I have searched for an appropriate answer but can't find any to this question. It is very simple, apart from reports, is there a way I can print a webform i.e send the page design to the printer. If yes, is there also a way to print a selected panel or section of the webpage?

Here is what I have been working with but it prints the whole damn thing, making it look clunky.

```
<asp:Button ID="btn_printButton" runat="server" Text="Print" OnClientClick="javascript:window.print();" BorderStyle="None" />
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no; you cannot print your webpage partially.

It is the responsibility of the browser; Javascript and ASP.Net do not have control over the browser.

If you want to print partial, you need to render that partial html in a separate Browser Window (or separate tab) which you normally can in ASP.Net MVC.

Since you are using Web Form, you are out of luck.

Comment: Ah, I see. So I have to use a report then. Well, been trying to do that and still having errors with the it having parameters i want to use dynamically